# How to crop Camera2 preview without overlay object?

Tags: android, android-camera2

I want to crop the camera preview in Android using camera2 api. I am using [android-Camera2Basic](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic) the official example.

This is the result I am getting
[image]

And, the result exactly I want to achieve is this
[image]

I don't want to overlay the object on textureView. I want it actually to be of this size without stretching.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to edit the image yourself before drawing it, since the default behavior of a TextureView is to just draw the whole image sent to its Surface.
And adjusting the TextureView's transform matrix will only scale or move the whole image, not crop it.

Doing this requires quite a bit of boilerplate, since you need to re-implement most of a TextureView.  For best efficiency, you likely want to implement the cropping in OpenGL ES; so you'll need a GLSurfaceView, and then you need to use the OpenGL context of that GLSurfaceView to create a SurfaceTexture object, and then using that texture, draw a quadrilateral with the cropping behavior you want in the fragment shader.

That's fairly basic EGL, but it's quite a bit if you've never done any OpenGL programming before.  There's a small test program within the Android OS tree that uses this kind of path: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/native/+/master/opengl/tests/gl2_cameraeye/#

Comment: Actually, I have to capture a fingerprint that's why I have to focus a finger in front of the camera. I have observed that if the camera view filled with the full hand in front of the camera the autofocus works very well and focuses the hand but if I put finger at the same distance it never focuses. That's why I want to shrink the preview near to the width of finger so that I can fill the entire preview and get autofocus perfectly. The solution you have provided I'll surely look into this. Kindly suggest me a better approach if there is. Thank you.

Comment: If you want to direct autofocus to a specific area, you can use the https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureRequest#CONTROL_AF_REGIONS control.  Cropping the preview after capture has no effect on what the camera tries to focus on.

Comment: @EddyTalvala unfortunately your link is broken in the original answer. could you edit it? I am trying hardly to understand how to crop each frame (because moving crop window) of the camera stream before preview it - never done openGL - where should I start? anything would be nice! open bounty: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62375930/how-can-i-crop-the-live-feed-from-the-camera-on-each-frame-on-android

Comment: Sorry for that! I've fixed the link to be https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/native/+/master/opengl/tests/gl2_cameraeye/#