# How can I crop the live feed from the camera on each frame on Android?

Tags: android, video, android-camera, frame, textureview

I have the video preview from the camera which I want to crop.

But the cropping window is changing frame by frame (size and position of the cropping window).

How could I achieve this on Android (flutter, kotlin, java, nativescript,.. doesn't matter) to be able to show the live cropping results in a view and also be able to save the result to file?

I don't want the code, I just don't know which libraries and api's to use (link too documentation) and how the concept should be solved for this problem.

How to crop the live video from camera frame by frame and preview and save to file?

I [created (partially) what I want in Javascript](https://jsfiddle.net/7y0n21Lv/), just to show what I mean. In Javascript I use a HTML Video-tag (this could get the feed from the Webcam) then I create a Canvas and can read each frame of the video-tag as data and select exactly what I want from frame to frame.

```
 let a = 10;
 processor.computeFrame = function computeFrame() {
       let frame = ctx.getImageData(a,0, this.width*0.5 +a, this.height); // here I use a moving window from left to right for the crop
       ctx2.drawImage(frame, 0, 0); // and draw it back to the view (second canvas)
       a +=0.1; //move the window
};
```

How can I solve this in Android?

I don't expect a fully working code... if you have any good articles, tutorials or documentation where I should start to read to achieve this, it would be perfect!

Interesting article:

- https://engineering.depop.com/android-square-video-cropping-59b5edd69bce
- https://www.programmersought.com/article/3222812179/

Answer (score 0):

If you just wanted to crop preview, you could use a TextureView and update its [transform matrix](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/view/TextureView#settransform) to match your desired crop rectangle.

If all you need is an occasional screen grab at the same resolution as preview for saving, you could use [TextureView.getBitmap](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/view/TextureView#getbitmap) to read the cropped view to a Bitmap, and then save it.

If you need a higher-resolution or higher-quality capture, you'll need a separate output from the camera.  Options are either capturing JPEG, decoding it, cropping the resulting Bitmap, and re-encoding it (assuming you want to save a JPEG, anyway), or capturing uncompressed YUV, cropping it, and then converting it to a Bitmap.

The [CameraX Android support library](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/camera) might save you a lot of time in setting up the high-quality path, though I think you still need to do the cropping yourself for the output of the ImageCapture use case.

Comment: CameraX was the right hint! I still think its not done.. somehow you need to take the frames from CameraX and crop it. And I can not find any documentation how to crow each frame differently.